# Connecting android app to gmail server

Tags: java, android, gmail

Is there any way that i can connect my android application to gmail server so that i can sign in, sign up and get my contacts from there. What i am doing is developing an android application which has to connect to gmail server and get my gmail contacts from there once i sign in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gmail in normal email service so you can use imap to connect and download data.

Comment: I am basically talking in terms that is there is some API which would enable me to get connected to gmail server. Kindly provide me with some links and code snippets in this regard. Thanks.